# Is there any SDK available for Apple TV?

Tags: sdk, tvos, apple-tv

Is there any SDK available for Apple TV?

Answer (score 2):

Things have changed in the years since this question was asked...

There's a [new Apple TV](http://apple.com/tv/) (4th generation) with updated hardware comparable to 2014-2015 iOS devices, and with it a new OS derived from iOS. Unlike with the past Apple TVs, [tvOS](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/) is an open platform for developers, featuring its own App Store.

The old Apple TV (3rd generation) is still available as of this writing, but is unchanged -- it's still a closed (iOS-based) platform without developer support from Apple.

Answer (score -1):

This answer was provided 4 years ago.

*No.  To do anything interesting with it, you have to Hack/Jailbreak it -- all unsupported of course.*

No need to down vote anymore, thanks. Feel free to refer to the other answers.